# Nominatim import of data import results in Segmentation fault

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu-18.04, nominatim

I have a VPS with 6 core, 60GB RAM and 1TB SSD space.

I installed Nominatim on Ubuntu 18.04 following the official installation here [Nominatim Installation](http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/)

I tried to import the openstreet planet pbf file located here [Planet OpenStreetMap](https://planet.openstreetmap.org/)

> ./utils/setup.php --osm-file planet-latest.osm.pbf --all
>   --osm2pgsql-cache 28000 2>&1 | tee setup.log

After few hours I got the error Segmentation fault ERROR: No Data see below:

```
> 2019-11-30 16:50:55 == Setup DB Postgres version found: 10 Postgis
> version found: 2.4  set_config
> ------------
> 
> (1 row)
> 
> 2019-11-30 16:51:04 == Import data osm2pgsql version 1.2.0 (64 bit id
> space)
> 
> Allocating memory for dense node cache Processing: Node(618450k
> 2425.3k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s) Allocating memory for sparse node cache Sharing dense sparse Node-cache: cache=28000MB,
> maxblocks=448000*65536, allocation method=11 Mid: loading persistent
> node cache from /srv/nominatim/flatnode/flatnode.file Mid: pgsql,
> cache=28000 Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes Setting up table:
> planet_osm_ways Setting up table: planet_osm_rels Processing:
> Node(621390k 2427.3k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0
> 0.00/s)import-full.style'. Using projection SRS 4326 (Latlong) NOTICE:  table "place" does not exist, skipping
> 
> Reading in file:
> /srv/nominatim/Nominatim-3.4.0/build/planet-latest.osm.pbf Using PBF
> parser. Processing: Node(5612922k 3148.0k/s) Way(437617k 33.05k/s)
> Relation(0 0.00/s)Segmentation fault ERROR: No Data string(7) "No
> Data"
```

Any idea why I got this error please?
Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a bug reporting tool. Check https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/issues instead.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/71917/nominatim-import-of-data-import-results-in-segmentation-fault